# gradlew will not sign a debug build

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

I am working on a CICD pipeline for a React Native Android mobile application using AWS Code Build and Code Pipeline.

When build a debug bundle (`./gradlew bundleDebug`) the resulting `.aab` file is not signed:

```
>keytool -printcert -jarfile app-debug.aab
Not a signed jar file
```

When I build a release bundle (`./gradlew bundleRelease`) the resulting `.aab` file is signed properly.

This is the relevant portion of my build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('release.keystore')
            storePassword System.getenv('GOOGLE_KEYSTORE_PWD')
            keyAlias System.getenv('GOOGLE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS')
            keyPassword System.getenv('GOOGLE_KEYSTORE_PWD')
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

I inject the base64 decoded release certificate from AWS Secrets Manager into the project source at `android/app/release.keystore` in the build script. The `debug.keystore`, `release.keystore` and `build.gradle` exist in the code repo at `android/app/`. `gradlew bundleXXXX` is run from the `android` directory.

Initially, when I ran `gradlew signingReport` it recognized both the `release` and `debug` keystores in the codebuild source location `/codebuild/output/src634901523/src/android/app/`. But, it was followed by several `missing keystore` errors for `/root/.android/debug.keystore`.

```
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   > Task :app:signingReport
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Variant: debug
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Config: debug
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Store: /codebuild/output/src634901523/src/android/app/debug.keystore
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Alias: androiddebugkey
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   MD5: 20:F4:61:48:B7:2D:8E:5E:5C:A2:3D:37:A4:F4:14:90
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   SHA1: 5E:8F:16:06:2E:A3:CD:2C:4A:0D:54:78:76:BA:A6:F3:8C:AB:F6:25
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   SHA-256: FA:C6:17:45:DC:09:03:78:6F:B9:ED:E6:2A:96:2B:39:9F:73:48:F0:BB:6F:89:9B:83:32:66:75:91:03:3B:9C
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Valid until: Tuesday, April 30, 2052
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   ----------
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Variant: release
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Config: release
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Store: /codebuild/output/src634901523/src/android/app/release.keystore
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Alias: ***
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   MD5: ***
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   SHA1: ***
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   SHA-256: ***
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Valid until: Saturday, May 28, 2050
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   ----------
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Variant: debugAndroidTest
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Config: debug
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Store: /codebuild/output/src634901523/src/android/app/debug.keystore
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Alias: androiddebugkey
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   MD5: 20:F4:61:48:B7:2D:8E:5E:5C:A2:3D:37:A4:F4:14:90
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   SHA1: 5E:8F:16:06:2E:A3:CD:2C:4A:0D:54:78:76:BA:A6:F3:8C:AB:F6:25
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   SHA-256: FA:C6:17:45:DC:09:03:78:6F:B9:ED:E6:2A:96:2B:39:9F:73:48:F0:BB:6F:89:9B:83:32:66:75:91:03:3B:9C
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Valid until: Tuesday, April 30, 2052
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   ----------
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   > Task :react-native-app-auth:signingReport
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Variant: debugAndroidTest
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Config: debug
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Store: /root/.android/debug.keystore
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Alias: AndroidDebugKey
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Error: Missing keystore
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   ----------
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:signingReport
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Variant: debugAndroidTest
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Config: debug
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Store: /root/.android/debug.keystore
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Alias: AndroidDebugKey
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   Error: Missing keystore
2023-01-11T09:26:22.714-05:00   ----------
...
```

So, in my build script, I also copied the `debug.keystore` to `/root/.android/debug.keystore` and this removed all `missing keystore` errors in the `signingReport`.

However, I still cannot get any debug `.aab` signed. While, the release `.aab` is signed with the `release` certificate properly.

I've tried many different combinations of `build.gradle` settings and providing the keystore files in different locations. Including adding an equivalent `debug` build type which references the `debug` `signingConfig`. Nothing will fix this issue I can find. Prior to this endeavor, we were successfully building a signed `.apk` using the debug.keystore as a `release` type with `./gradlew assembleRelease`. But now I need to have a production bundle I can upload to Google signed with a valid cert, while keeping the lower level environments signed with the `debug.keystore`.

Answer (score 0):

Perharps, you need to create a debug build type. You only have a  release build type for now.

```
buildTypes {
    release{
               // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
                // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
    
    debug{
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                minifyEnabled true //false ?
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did try that, but it didn't make any difference. My understanding is that the `debug` build type does not need to be included because it will default to using the `debug` signing config when using `gradlew bundleDebug`. Unless the desire is to override certain default settings.

Comment: However, I'm not sure if this is a clue or related in anyway. Even with the minifyEnabled setting set to true and configured as you have shown, the debug bundle is almost twice the size as the release version.

Comment: Previously the developers setup all releases to be the `release` type. I am the one that segregated the two. Making prod be `release` and all others be `debug`. From what I can tell the devs did not configure things or setup things accordingly to support the two release types. I'm not a dev, and am not too concerned about this. I modified my CICD pipeline to make them all `release` type again, and then I just replace the signing info dynamically depending on the environment.